# Get back original x:xs

Tags: list, haskell, return

I want to create a function in Haskell which is like this:

encode :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> String

I have a "dictionary" function called "table" which creates a list of pairs:

```
table :: Int -> [Char] -> [(Char, Char)]
table __ [] = []
table n l   = zip l (drop n (cycle l))
```

The encode function encodes a string by characters. So far it looks like this:

```
encode (x:xs) (n:ns)
| length(n:ns) > 1 && (fst x) == n  = [snd x] ++ (encode (x:xs) ns)
| length(xs) > 1 && (fst x) /= n    = encode xs (n:ns)
| length(ns) > 0 && length(xs) == 0 = encode (x:xs) ns
```

For the test `encode table2 "SOS"` it gives me only "U" but it needs to be "UQU".
the table2 is a constant: `table2 = table 2 (['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['.', '!', '?', ' '])`

My question is: How can I get back the original list of (x:xs)? I think I get only a "U" because I return with xs always and it cuts the first pair, but I need the whole original (x:xs) for every character.

the constant functions return: [picture](http://prntscr.com/6rat13)

Comment: Make a helper function in a `where` clause.

Comment: That would be `where` @AJFarmar

Comment: @MarcusFritzsch Oops, that's embarrassing!

Comment: Nah, happens to the best! :)

Comment: Could you explain what would the helper function exactly do? Sorry I'm still a newbie to Haskell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your function is when you search through the list of associations, you throw away the values at the beginning. You just need to retain a reference to that list. You can perform a transformation like

```
encode l n0 = encode' l n0 where 
  encode' (x:xs) (n:ns) 
    | ... = snd x : encode (x:xs) ns0
```

But you can recognize an even higher level of abstraction will make this a much simpler problem.

Assume you have an abstract type `Table` which can encode one `Char`. Encoding might fail (a character might not have an association) so it returns a `Maybe Char`:

```
type Table = ...
encode1 :: Table -> Char -> Maybe Char
```

Then to encode a whole string, just encode each character with the same table - if any returns `Nothing`, then return `Nothing`. A string is a list, and you need to apply a function with effects to each element of that list - this is precisely what `mapM` does:

```
encode :: Table -> [Char] -> Maybe Char
encode t = mapM (encode1 t)
```

Now the question of how to define `Table`. Since it represents an associative map, why not use an associative map datatype - `Data.Map`.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Table = M.Map Char Char 

encode1 :: Table -> Char -> Maybe Char 
encode1 = flip M.lookup 

table :: Int -> [Char] -> [(Char, Char)]
table _ [] = []
table n l   = zip l (drop n (cycle l))

table' :: Int -> [Char] -> Table
table' n l = M.fromList (table n l)
```

And now:

```
> encode (table 2 (['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['.', '!', '?', ' '])) "SOS"
Just "UQU"
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem here really stems from trying to do too much at once.  Instead of working with the whole string you want to encode, work with just a single character at a time.  If you can correctly encode one character, then you can encode them all:

```
encodeChar :: [(Char, Char)] -> Char -> Char
encodeChar table charToEncode = ???
```

To encode a single character we want to find the `pair` in `table` where `fst pair == c`.  This can be performed using basic recursion and pattern matching:

```
encodeChar [] _ = error "Empty table!"
encodeChar ((fromChar, toChar):restOfTable) charToEncode
    = if fromChar == charToEncode
        then toChar
        else encodeChar restOfTable charToEncode
```

However, it's bad practice to use `error`.  For most cases it'd be better to return a `Maybe` instead.  Luckily for us Haskell comes with a handy function called `lookup` that can do this entire operation for us, but first I'll show what it looks like to return `Maybe Char` manually:

```
encodeCharMaybe [] _ = Nothing
encodeCharMaybe ((fromChar, toChar):restOfTable) charToEncode
    = if fromChar == charToEncode
        then Just toChar
        else encodeCharMaybe restOfTable charToEncode
```

And with `lookup`:

```
encodeCharMaybe table charToEncode = lookup charToEncode table
```

Now we can implement `encode` more simply:

```
encode1 :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> String
encode1 table msg = map (encodeChar table) msg
```

Here the same `table` is used for each `encodeChar` call, which was causing you problems with your current implementation.  If you wanted to use proper error handling with `Maybe` you could implement it as

```
encode2 :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> Maybe String
encode2 table [] = Just []
encode2 table (c:msg) = do
    encodedC <- encodeCharMaybe table c
    encodedMsg <- encode2 table msg
    Just (encodedC : encodedMsg)
```

Or using `mapM`, which basically is just a generalization of this pattern

```
encode2 table msg = mapM (encodeCharMaybe table) msg
```

As mentioned in the comments above you could use a helper function in a `where` clause, and that would look something like

```
encode2 table msg = mapM (encodeCharMaybe table) msg
    where
        encodeCharMaybe table charToEncode = lookup charToEncode table
```

Although you could just write all of this in one function:

```
encode2 table msg = mapM (\charToEncode -> lookup charToEncode table) msg
```

And if you want to be confusing you can write this in [pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) style:

```
encode2 = mapM . flip lookup
```

But this is completely optional and certainly isn't the most intuitive explanation.  I only include it here to show off how awesome Haskell can be; your entire problem can be reduced to just a few built-in functions and a composition.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can use pattern matching to avoid checking the length of the list (x:xs).  It will be much easier to understand what is going on in your functions.

To answer your question, it looks like you are recursively calling encode in the second line and returning its value.  This will only end up returning the last result.  Prepend the intermediate encoded values with the `:` operator to get the full encoded string.